# CSS video background doesn't play on android's chrome

Tags: css, html

A simple one - here is my site - http://michaelmedvedskiy.website

I'm loading it through the same wifi network, in my pc browser the background video loads fine - [pc fullscreen perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ulw.jpg)

And if i stretch the screen down to the mobile's perspective it works fine as well - [pc stretched perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhuyt.png)

But on my mobile device (Sony Experia X5) it just doesn't load - [mobile perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFzOI.jpg)

Why so?

Hopefully, I wrote the question properly, if I didn't, please remark my flaws, I will correct them.

Comment: You should put your code in Codepen or somewhere to everyone can see and find any wrong in your code

Comment: What part of the code should I include?

Comment: Just important part. It's simple, read more about code in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Update: I tried to achieve this result with js through play() function, and this didn't work.

Comment: Show the code you use to play video in background

Comment: <div class = "videocont"> <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="myVideo">
  <source src="media/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> </div>- this is the html, video{
 min-width: 100%;

}

.videocont{
 
 margin-top: 0;
  position:relative;
 height: 90vh;
 overflow:hidden;
 
 
 }#myVideo {
    object-fit:cover;


}
this is the css

Answer (score 0):

Background videos are not auto playing on mobile devices. It's default setting. You may try to play manually using player API